# Preciso de ideias com formulario de checbox

Tags: php, html

Preciso alterar uma base de dados quando uma check-box for marcada - passando do padrao "N" para "S", porém existem varias checkbox na página e como cada registro da tabela tem a sua respectiva id e a opcao S ou N não posso tratar as checkbox como um array, alguém por favor teria uma ideia de como poderia fazer? eu ja tenho tudo pronto, só preciso alterar as opcoes entre S e N

Comment: Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o HTML que possui?

Comment: pronto, desculpe a demora

Comment: Não tem nada na pergunta de HTML.

Comment: O html da pergunta deve estar tipo hidden :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigo,

Se publica-se parte do código seria mais fácil te ajudar.

A lógica seria algo tipo:

```
$resul; //resultado do banco de dados
$opcao; // s ou n $_POST

foreach($result as $rs){ // loop com os dados do banco

if($rs['campo'] != $opcao){ // verifica se valor é diferente do que esta no banco...

update....

}
```

}

Comment: perdão, eu n tenho acesso aos códigos aqui em casa, mas obrigado pela ajuda, com certeza vai me ajudar